# Sending email from localhost server xampp/sendmail

Tags: php, email, sendmail.exe

I have set up a PHP site that will be locally hosted. One function of this is to send an email with items from a shopping cart. When hosted online (for testing) the email() function worked perfectly sending email.

I'm now transferring the site to a local machine, and am unable to send email.

Originally the emails came from servername@hostname.co.uk which worked well, although I'd happily set up a gmail or similar to handle the sending.

I've read a few tutorials about setting things up and have firstly tried using sendmail and a gmail address.

I'm wondering if there's something simple I've missed in setting up the ini files.

I edited my php.ini file as follows:

```
[mail function]
 XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
 SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port = 587

 For Win32 only.
 http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = shipimageemail@gmail.com

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

and then my sendmail.ini file as follows:

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=shipimageemail@gmail.com
auth_password=password
force_sender=shipimageemail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Should the first line of [mail_function] be commented out?

Comment: http://newcoderslife.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/how-to-use-xampps-mail-server-mercury-mail/ Nice Tutorial using mail from localhost through mercury in XAMPP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

sendmail.ini

[sendmail]

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=[email]@gmail.com
auth_password=[email password]
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=[email]@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

php.ini

[mail function]

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart Apache