# codeigniter localhost email not sending

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, yahoo

I have some problem and I don't understand. 
This is my code

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;


$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('rudzstyle@yahoo.co.id', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('rudzstyle@gmail.com');
$message = $data->nama_depan.'<br>'.$this->input->post('snk');
$this->email->subject($message);
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

that 2 email are active email.

and the result of the debugger is this

> Exit status code: 1 Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check
>   settings. Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might
>   not be configured to send mail using this method.
>
> User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Mon, 2 Jun 2014 07:53:21 +0200 From:
>   "Your Name"  Return-Path:  To: rudzstyle@gmail.com Subject:
>   =?iso-8859-1?Q?Riyanto test?= 
>   =?iso-8859-1?Q??= Reply-To: "rudzstyle@yahoo.co.id"  X-Sender: rudzstyle@yahoo.co.id X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3
>   (Normal) Message-ID: <538c1151179cb@yahoo.co.id> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> Testing the email class.

Comment: you are using windows are linux ?

Comment: Try Test Mail Server Tool >> http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Comment: @SohailYasmin i use xampp sir

Comment: @Bora i use xampp localhost sir, and i want to send email from localhost

Comment: @rudzstyle this tool for sending mail from localhost. It's not real sending mail, tool is listening port and get the emails.

Comment: @Bora okey sir, i will give it a try. but i think my problem is this error.. Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail

Comment: @rudzstyle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327913/sending-email-from-localhost-server-xampp-sendmail

Comment: You can't send email from localhost in windows , because you dont have any email server installed default in xamp or wamp you need to install it manualy

Comment: @SohailYasmin how to install it sir?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Codeigniter, Try this

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol']='smtp';
$config['smtp_host']='your host';
$config['smtp_port']='465';
$config['smtp_timeout']='30';
$config['smtp_user']='your mail id';
$config['smtp_pass']='your password';
$config['charset']='utf-8';
$config['newline']="\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('no-reply@your-site.com', 'Site name');
$this->email->to('to-address-mail-id');
$this->email->subject('Notification Mail');
$this->email->message('Your message');
$this->email->send();
```

In `$config['smtp_user']` field,give your email_id and in `$config['smtp_pass']` field,provide your password for that mail.

This will work.Just try it.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: what is the smtp_host of yahoo anyway? i have trouble finding it

Comment: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
use port 995

Answer (score 0):

You can find your solution from these two links 
     [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2009/03/setting-up-local-mail-smtp-pop3-imap.html