# Exit status code: 72 Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->config->load('email');
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('vjdabur@gmail.com', 'vijay');
$this->email->to('vjdabur@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

I dont know what I have missed in above code, I have sendmail installed in my `usr/sbin/sendmail` path.I am trying to send mail in PHP `Codeigniter`.But I am getting

> Exit status code: 72  Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.

Comment: Can anyone guide me from this problem?

Comment: [Stack Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988146/codeigniter-localhost-email-not-sending)

Comment: I dont have smtp installed so cannot use it and also I cannot install it ,I dont have permission to install.I can use only sendmail.