# want to send an email from localhost in Codeigniter and i'm using lampp

Tags: codeigniter

i want to send an email from my local host using code igniter. I'm using lamp here.  My code shows below error

```
Exit status code: 127
Unable to open a socket to `Sendmail`. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using `PHP` `Sendmail`. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Date: Fri, 12 May 2017 08:01:46 +0200
From: "`jatin`" 
Return-Path: <xxx>
To: xxx
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Hi..=20?=
Reply-To: <xxx>
User-Agent: `CodeIgniter`
X-Sender: xxx
X-Mailer: `CodeIgniter`
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <xxx>
Mime-Version: 1.0

    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Comment: Please remove personal data before posting online.

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP mailer for sending mail.

using this you can send mail easily without any warning and error

Download PHP mailer from here: [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

```
require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP(); 
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
            $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";     
            $mail->Port       = 465;                   
            $mail->Username   = "test@gmail.com";  // your email address
            $mail->Password   = "test";            // your gmail password
            $mail->SetFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Test');  //sender mail address
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject    = "Subject";
            $mail->Body      = 'hello there';
            $destino = 'test@gmail.com'; // receiver email address
            $mail->AddAddress($destino, "Receiver");
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
```

You have to set access for less trusted apps in your Gmail account also:

1. Login to your gmail account
2. Click on MyAccount from Google Apps
3. Click on 'Signing in to Google' from left panel
4. And Turn on 'Allow less secure apps' from bottom of page

now try to send mail.it's works 100%.

Comment: copied from [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988146/codeigniter-localhost-email-not-sending) You can mention actual link to answer rather than coping.

Comment: not copied from anywhere. I use this solution in my project.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to localhost:465 (Connection refused)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2063

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/jatin_EmailSend/application/controllers/Email_Control.php
Line: 86
Function: send

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/jatin_EmailSend/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
An Error Was Encountered

The following SMTP error was encountered: 111 Connection refused
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: make sure your `php_sockets` extension enabled.

Comment: it is enabled in php.ini file. ;extension=php_sockets.dll